# VB6 Loading .net 4 C# COM dll from Windows 7 to Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, com, vb6

I have a C# ComVisible Class Library dll created on .Net Framework 4.5 environment - but the dll target framework is set to Framework 3.5
I have created the COM dll and added it to a GAC using Visual Studio 2012 
I add this dll as a reference in my legacy VB6 project ( from Project->Add Reference).
Everything works fine. All this is done in Windows 7.

Now, I use the same dll on Windows XP which has .net Framework 4.0.
I add the dll into the GAC on Windows XP. 
But I am unable to locate the dll in VB to add it as reference.
Could you please tell me what I might be missing. In my XP machine, the dll is present in: C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL location

Any idea what I am missing here, please ?

**EDIT:** I have also registered the assembly with regasm utility.
Any changes in the registry I should do to see my COM dll in 'available reference' list in my VB6 project??

Comment: You never mentioned registering the assembly with Regasm.exe.  That can be automatic on your dev machine with the "Register for COM interop" checkbox, just building the project is enough.  Not on that XP machine.  Be sure to use the correct one, you need the old one since you are targeted an ancient .NET framework version.  Do keep in mind that VB6 could not care less.

Answer (score -2):

When registering your assembly for COM you need to call

```
regasm myassembly.dll /codebase
```

The /codebase adds the relevant Registry entries that you VB6 application will use to find the DLL.

Comment: No, it is the /tlb option that matters here.

Comment: It depends on whether the user is trying to use the DLL on the second computer in VB6 to do development or just trying to run the compiled application. The tlb file isn't needed when deployed so if the user is just trying to run the application on the second computer then /codebase is all that's needed.

Comment: Again, no.  The codebase option is not applicable when the assembly is installed in the GAC, which the OP is doing.  See [Regasm.exe (Assembly Registration Tool)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(v=vs.110).aspx).  As @Hans states, it is the /tlb option that's relevant.

Comment: I stand corrected as far as the /codebase option. I do not put my COM exposed assemblies in the GAC so didn't realize it wasn't required. I still don't see why the need for creating the TLB though. I've been distributing a COM exposed assembly with my application for the past 3 years and I just register it in the install directory with /codebase. I do not distribute or recreate the tlb. From a bit of searching it sounds like there's cases where it is required if you're using threading but I believe in most cases it is not needed.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I'm thinking of moving this out of GAC and make it a private COM assembly instead and use regasm.